# functools total_ordering doesn't appear to do anything with inherited class

Tags: python, oop, functools

I am trying sort a list of strings in a way that uses a special comparison. I am trying to use `functools.total_ordering`, but I'm not sure whether it's filling out the undefined comparisons correctly.

The two I define ( > and ==) work as expected, but < does not. In particular, I print all three and I get that `a > b` and `a < b`. How is this possible? I would think that total_ordering would simply define `<` as `not > and not ==`. The result of my `<` test is what you would get with regular str comparison, leading me to believe that total_ordering isn't doing anything.

Perhaps the problem is that I am inheriting str, which already has `__lt__` implemented? If so, is there a fix to this issue?

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class SortableStr(str):

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self+other > other+self

    #Is this necessary? Or will default to inherited class?
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str(self) == str(other)

def main():

    a = SortableStr("99")
    b = SortableStr("994")

    print(a > b)
    print(a == b)
    print(a < b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

OUTPUT:

```
True
False
True
```

Comment: You said that you think "the logic is[n't] super relevant for my question". Could you share it anyway? If you explain what results you expect to see, someone may be able to offer an alternative solution. For example, what do you expect `"555" < "555999"` to be? Or `"555" > "555999"`?

Comment: Why are you comparing `next_dig` to a digit in the *same* string?

Comment: Ah, just read your question a bit more closely. You say that you're getting the expected values of `True` for `a > b` and `False` for `a == b`, but you're getting an unexpected result of `True` for `a < b`.

Comment: I simplified the question, my new code gets the same result. For context, I'm working on this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/solution/

Comment: In the leetcode solution, they only implement __ lt __, which is interesting, I guess that's all that's needed for sort to work. But I'm still curious to learn about total_ordering and why this isn't working.

Comment: @PaulM. Hopefully that clears it up. I'm expecting True False False.

Comment: @PaulFornia Lots of Python built-ins, including sorting, are guaranteed to only use `__lt__`, to make it easier and more consistent to use a variety of different classes with it. See [Sorting HOW TO#Odds and Ends](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends). This is also true in C++, where most built-in algorithms are guaranteed to use `operator<` instead of requiring all ordering operations.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that's very good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the built-in `str` comparison operators are interfering with your code. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)

> Given a class defining one or more rich comparison ordering methods, this class decorator supplies the rest.

So it only supplies the ones not already defined. In your case, the fact that some of them are defined in a parent class is undetectable to `total_ordering`.

Now, we can dig deeper into the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Lib/functools.py#L188) and find the exact check

```
roots = {op for op in _convert if getattr(cls, op, None) is not getattr(object, op, None)}
```

So it checks if the values are equal to the ones defined in the root object `object`. We can make that happen

```
@total_ordering
class SortableStr(str):

    __lt__ = object.__lt__
    __le__ = object.__le__
    __ge__ = object.__ge__

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self+other > other+self

    #Is this necessary? Or will default to inherited class?
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str(self) == str(other)
```

Now `total_ordering` will see that `__lt__`, `__le__`, and `__ge__` are equal to the "original" `object` values and overwrite them, as desired.

---

This all being said, I would argue that this is a poor use of inheritance. You're violating [Liskov substitution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) at the very least, in that mixed comparisons between `str` and `SortableStr` are going to, to put it lightly, produce counterintuitive results.

My more general recommendation is to favor [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and, rather than defining a thing that "is a" specialized string, consider defining a type that "contains" a string and has specialized behavior.

```
@total_ordering
class SortableStr:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.value + other.value > other.value + self.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value
```

There, no magic required. Now `SortableStr("99")` is a valid object that is *not* a string but exhibits the behavior you want.

Comment: Just a thought, but could this be made to work with a [`collections.UserString`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserString)? I'm guessing no, because the docs explicitly say that it supports the "methods and operations" of normal strings, and I'm guessing those magic methods fall in that category.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! So regarding my question to Paul M below about "un" implementing a method, I think the answer is that `__lt__ = object.__lt__` effective does that. Interesting. But point definitely taken about inheritance not being the cleanest approach here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is correct, but glancing at the documentation of [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering), this stands out to me:

> Given a class defining one or more rich comparison ordering methods,
> this class decorator supplies **the rest**.

Emphasis mine. Your class inherits `__lt__` from `str`, so it does not get re-implemented by `total_ordering` since it isn't missing. That's my best guess.

Comment: Ok yeah I think you are right. So is there a fix? Is there a way to "un" implement a method without overwriting it? If not, then I guess `functools.total_ordering` just doesn't really work in this situation?

Comment: Looks like @SilvioMayolo just posted a more comprehensive answer reaching the same conclusion. Take a look!